# add div inner div using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a parent div like this

```
<div class="parent">
     <span>1</span>
     <span>2</span>
     <span>3</span>
</div>
```

I want to add a div after div.parent

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="subparent">
          <span>1</span>
          <span>2</span>
          <span>3</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

How can I do like this.

How can I do like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```js
$('<div class="subparent">').append($('.parent').children())
.appendTo('.parent')

console.log($('.parent').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
     <span>1</span>
     <span>2</span>
     <span>3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @TiếnHoàng you are welcome. Are you from Vietnam? I like 'bun cha'